# Is there any United States slang I should avoid in the UK or Ireland?

Tags: usa, uk, culture, ireland, american-english

We'll be spending a couple weeks this summer in the UK (Scotland and London), then a week in Ireland.  Is there any slang common in the United States that we be best avoided in either country?  For example, 'fag' is commonly used in the UK for cigarettes, but it's considered a slur in the US.

Comment: Suggest converting this to community wiki, and maybe migrating to english.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Calling someone a cigarette in the US would probably be considered a slur as well :)

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1999/words-with-opposite-meanings-in-different-regions

Comment: Since most of the answers deal with normal terms rather than slang terms we should really edit this question.

Comment: Not exactly slang but movie "Free Willy" had to be renamed in the UK so not to confuse it with being porn.

Comment: Is the flip flops/thongs thing an issue or are US/UK on the same page about that? I've seen it missunderstood to hilarious effect here in Oz -- I offered to take my friends new UK girlfriend thong shopping so she could enjoy our beautiful beaches...

Comment: @Molomby We call the shoes flipflops and the underwear thongs in the UK.

Comment: @Karlson: I'm pretty sure it was called Free Willy here in the UK. It just meant that a lot of people giggled a lot about it. :) We aren't actually stupid enough to think it was porn. :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Avoid the use of the word "fanny", as it is slang for, ah, a woman's front bits.  Be *very* careful when referring to your fanny pack!

Also, if an attractive member of the opposite sex asks you if you have a "rubber", double-check to make sure there aren't any chalkboards around because you're probably being asked for an *eraser*.

Comment: Dont spoil it, always gives us a giggle when Americans start talking about fanny.

Answer (score 35):

US "pants" = UK "trousers".
UK "pants" = US "underpants" or for some people "shorts".

Comment: ^^ this. So many friends who moved to the UK, so many embarrassing moments just because of this difference.

Comment: Not quiet a rude as "fanny", but definitely relevant since we'll be stopping at places to get laundry done.  Thanks!

Comment: None of these four words (pants, shorts, trousers, underpants) are slang as the OP requested though. Should we edit the question to not focus on slang?

Answer (score 20):

I heard an "Irish Car Bomb" and "Black and Tan" are types of cocktails/drinks. These are not terms that would be understood in Ireland, nor terms that are particularly nice.

The Irish Car Bomb one is obvious. "Black and Tans" were a group of British merceneries sent over in the Irish War of Independence in 1920s which were not exactly very honourable military people. They are viewed by Irish people the same way African-Americans might view the Klan. [Nike](http://www.irishtimes.com/newspaper/breaking/2012/0316/breaking2.html) and [Ben & Jerry's](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/2006/apr/19/ireland) have made this mistake.

Your example of fag is technically correct, but remember that "fag" would also be understood as an offensive slur in the UK & Ireland aswell, mostly depending on context/tone.

Comment: In the US, both terms are common in bars. A 'black and tan' is half a Guiness floated on top of half a Harp or Bass beer.  A car bomb is a shot of Bailey's irish cream, dropped into a Guiness, and then chugged.  

I wasn't aware of the Black and Tans history in Ireland, so this is good to know.

Comment: Imagine if there was a drink called "Twin Towers" (there isn't AFAIK). Should you ask for that in New York? That's like asking for an "Irish Car Bomb" here (the police in Ireland find about 20 bombs per year in Ireland)

Comment: @Rory In that case, we'd rename it to "Freedom Towers" and slap a flag on the glass.

Comment: A Black and Tan is relatively common amongst an older drinking generation in bars in Scotland.

Comment: *Your example of fag is technically correct, but remember that "fag" would also be understood as an offensive slur in the UK & Ireland aswell, mostly depending on context/tone.* Yes, it's entirely dependent on context. *Calling* someone a fag would be an insult, even though you can refer to cigarettes as fags as well.

Comment: I have a UK friend who once mentioned that he was able to 'bum a fag' while we were in the US. What he actually meant was that he was able to score a free cigarette from a stranger; how it was interpreted by everyone else around him was something else completely.

Answer (score 16):

I have often heard Americans use the words "poof" and "poofy" to describe what English people would call "puffy". For example: "That pillow is poofy." It should be understood that "poof" and "poofy" in England are slang for homosexual.

Comment: That's actually a pronunciation difference. They would still write it "puffy".

Comment: Correct. Offensive slang, like "faggot".

Comment: Faggot is pretty old fashioned term these days.

Comment: in most of the world, a faggot is a musical instrument :)

Comment: A faggot is a meatball, or possibly a bundle of sticks.

Answer (score 12):

Would probably avoid trying to make jokes about "bad teeth" and horrible food as well. Brits in general don't take to kindly to jokes like that. In fact, I'm currently living in the states and some of the clichés the Americans have about us I can't understand where they even came from.

Also, if someone calls you a "yank" they don't mean to be offensive. It's quite common in the UK to refer to the Americans as yanks.

There's not a lot you guys say that offends us in general. Don't make the mistake of calling an Irish, Welsh or Scotsman English or you'll probably be ruined for ignorance.

Comment: The USA seems to have a steryotype of "British Bad Teeth", but I don't think that's a stereyotype that the British are aware of it, so you might get confused looks if you joke about it. Some countries are aware of the steryotypes of themselves (e.g. Irish & drinking), and might understand if you are making a joke, but the "British Bad Teeth" seems to be a USA idea.

Joking about food as a USAian would be odd, since the USA isn't exactly known for it's culinary excellence (compared to say, France)

Comment: @Rory. One of the American guests on QI was once talking about bad British food, and Stephen Fry quelled him with "And this from a country that has spray-on cheese?"

Comment: @Timothy The problem in the USA seems to be that teeth are viewed as health indicator. So US citizens in general use everything to prop up their teeth: Repairing, whitening, symmetric placement (even if it does more internal, non-visible damage to the teeth). As everyone does it, they subconsciously expect perfect white teeth and evaluate normal teeth from other cultures (Europe in general, not only British) as "bad teeth".

Answer (score 8):

if you offer someone 'a ride', as in "I'd love to give you a ride" you will be offering something more intimate than a car journey. Use 'do you want a lift' if offering to drive someone to their destination

Comment: So has Uber taken off then?!

Answer (score 7):

It applies to gestures too. If you're holding up two fingers to mean *two* (two pints, for example), be sure to do so palm out. Holding up two fingers palm in, especially if accompanied by an upward motion, is rather rude. (In the south of Europe it indicates a cuckold; in the UK and Ireland it doesn't have that specific meaning, but it's still rude.)

You may hear fanciful stories about how this gesture originated from the Battle of Agencourt. These stories are not true.

Comment: US, UK & Ireland all have the "2 fingers" insult (right?) so I'd presume an american wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: @Rory. I thought the US had only the single-finger insult ("flipping the bird"). I've certainly seen an American woman use two fingers in the bar when ordering. It was perfectly clear what she meant, and the staff weren't at all offended, but I warned her anyway, for future reference, as in other cases her meaning might not be as clearly apparent.

Comment: Oh. I did not know. Maybe you're right. (Scratch that up to another 'I thought everyone did that'). Any USAians care to comment?

Comment: USAian here.  I've *never* seen the two-finger gesture (index and middle fingers raised) used as an insult.  It normally just means "two" (or going back further, "peace" or "victory").  The only insulting gesture I know that's recognized throughout the US is the one-finger (raised middle finger, normally with palm in).

Comment: @NateEldredge: UK/Euro victory/peace sign will also be palm forward, despite the famous photo of Churchill doing it the US way.

Comment: Also, continuing the gestural tangent, American-style cutlery handling may make people think you don't have full use of your left hand...

Comment: @e100, what do you mean by "American-style cutlery handling"?

Comment: There's a song about an Irish emigrant to New York which contains the line "My kids know how to use the correct knife and fork". On the other hand, I handle my own cutlery American-style, because my left hand is always fully occupied holding a book. @Joe.

Comment: @TRiG, but what is "American-style cutlery handling"?  By your comment, I get the impression that it has something to do with leaving your left hand free.

Comment: @Joe:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_utensil_etiquette#American_style

Comment: @e100, I'm an American, and I don't think I've ever seen that use of utensils.

Answer (score 4):

- Elevator = lift
- Garage/ parking lot = car park
- Hot chips/ French fries = chips
- Chips/ potato chips = crisps
- Route is pronounced root.
- Side walk = pavement
- Jelly = jam
- Jello = jelly

Comment: All true, but none of these would lead to embarrassing situations.

Comment: Well if you don't count being made fun of in a loud and public way. Or maybe that's just my English friends who like to give loud lectures on how the colonies and former colonies have ruined their language.

Comment: The US "Jelly" = UK "Jam" thing took me ages. I wonder what monstrosity a (US) "peanut butter and jelly sandwich" was until I realised it was uk "jam", not uk "jelly"

Comment: (Hard cider = cider. Old Rosie right at the moment, which is definitely alcoholic.)

Comment: I never heard (hot) chips called "chips" in the US (except in British themed fish n chip shops). Only ever "French fries" or just plain "fries". Even if they were pretty chunky, in which case they might have some adjective before "fries".

Comment: Yes all "cider" in the UK & Ireland is as alcoholic as beer. I always thought it strange to see Ned Flanders enthusiastically talking about cider on the Simpsons.

Answer (score 2):

For those with more time thean sense :

look at the lists of false friends from wikipedia: [a-l](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_words_having_different_meanings_in_British_and_American_English%3a_A%E2%80%93L) [m-z](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_words_having_different_meanings_in_British_and_American_English%3a_M%E2%80%93Z)
Some could be offensive, others not so, but also beware of things like [rhyming slang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyming_slang) found mostly in east London.

Answer (score 2):

"Restroom" *may* be understood, but "bathroom" means exactly what it says
(you know, shower & bath) and "prop room" is unknown.
What you mean is either "public conveniences" if you are extremely polite, 
but "toilet" and "loo" are the well known terms you search.

Comment: Asking for "gents" and "ladies" is OK too.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This may help you. copied from here: http://funnychutkule.com/3446/british-vs-american-english-words-differences/

Comment: Not a lot of actual slang in there though, and not a lot that needs avoiding either.

Comment: Scotch tape is the really good quality sellotape which doesn't yellow with age and peels off without tearing. A yard is a concrete area: it may be a goods yard, or may be part of a garden. (My parents' house has a yard: the garden is beyond it. Or it may be considered part of the garden, perhaps.)